# If ... do this if statement?

Tags: php, if-statement

I am stuck on some php coding, that seemed initially easy to accomplish. Here is what i would like to do :

```
<?php
$amountOfDigits = 1;
$numbers = range(1,3);
shuffle($numbers);

for($i = 0;$i < $amountOfDigits;$i++)
$digits .= $numbers[$i];

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
static $count = 0;

if ($digits == '1') { 
//Do this if statement
if ($count == "2") }
elseif ($digits == '2') { 
//Do this if statement
if ($count == "2" || $count == "3") }
elseif ($digits == '3') { 
//Do this if statement
if ($count == "2" || $count == "3" || $count == "4") }

 { //here the rest of the code
```

?>

So depending on the $digits variable, the if statement is formatted to be used on the line above `//the rest of the code`

How to put this in PHP properly?

Thanks.
Robbert

Comment: Can you describe what it's supposed to do?

Comment: So, what's wrong? This if sequence is perfectly legal.

Comment: First, don't use the static keyword outside of a class. Next, actually I have no idea what you're trying to do with this.

Comment: If you post code that doesn't do what you want it to do, and then say it describes what you're trying to accomplish, it will be hard to give you a good answer

Comment: How is this code okay? Doing "if(condition) } " makes no sense. If statements need to be followed by blocks of code.

Comment: I am sorry, this code i just made up to explain what i am trying to do. So if a variable then do this if statement, elseif this variable do this if statement etc. So in a nutshell: 
`if ($digits == '2') { 
//Do this if statement
if ($count == "2" || $count == "3") }
if ($digits == '3') { 
//Do this if statement
if ($count == "2" || $count == "3" || $count == "4") }

 { here the things to do based on the //do this if statement }` so i would like to echo a to do if statement based on a previous if statement.. Hope it is clear what i mean to do..

Comment: Is code under if statements the same?

Comment: @RobbertT you can edit your question instead of posting code in the comments.

Comment: @Daniel Figueroa done that, thanks

Comment: Thanks Robbert, I have a better sense of what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, you want something like this:

```
if ($digits == '1')  
    $mycond = ($count == "2");
elseif ($digits == '2') 
    $mycond = ($count == "2" || $count == "3") 
elseif ($digits == '3')  
    $mycond = ($count == "2" || $count == "3" || $count == "4")
```

then you can further use

```
if($mycond){
    // blahblahblah
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had this code already but it did not work at first. I thought this was just because of the code itself, but i had to do with something else in the script. All working now, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Well if you want the same execution block on each case, there is a very simple solution for that. 
You should simply use a function that check status of "count" depending on "digits".

```
<?php
    function checkCountAgainstDigits($count, $digits){
        switch($digits){
            case 1:
                return $count === 1;
            case 2:
                return $count === 2 || $count === 3;
            case 3:
                return $count === 2 || $count === 3 || $count === 4;
            default:
                // The default case "ELSE"
                return FALSE;
        }
    }

    if(checkCountAgainstDigits($count, $digits)){
        // do 
    }
?>
```

If you want a different one, your solution is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that opened my eyes. Nice way to accomplish it!